# Justification for applied mathematics

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I'm familiar with some philosophy of mathematics and what does mathematical knowledge mean (Plato, Kant, Frege, Brouwer etc.).  And as mathematicians, we establish a set of axioms and work up from there.  I'm wondering how are we able to make any predictions about our physical realm with our axioms?

For example, if we establish the Peano axioms of arithmetic and genetically construct a set of natural numbers, how can we make the leap and say that finite sets of physical objects will behave according to the arithmetic of natural numbers?

Comment: Because a finite set of e.g. eggs is a (partial) model of Peano axioms.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Do we know this by our intuition? We observe that for any set of *n* eggs, we can add 1 more.  Is there a justification of the statement that the peano axioms partially describe sets of finite eggs?   Also assuming there are a finite amount of eggs in the universe why are we allowed to say that peano axioms are true for the eggs if for some large *n*'s they are not true in the universe?